# output from multiple inputs, and the output will be split into separated names

Tags: awk

I tried to output from multiple inputs, and the output will be split into separated names according to the input variable.

From this input

==> input_A.txt <==

```
model
                 61096525  3380677 9639              
                 61096526  3382521 9634              
                 61096527  3384122 9651              
                 61096528  3384250 9675              
                 61096529  3384313 9706
```

==> input_B.txt <==

```
model
                 10911991  396855811255              
                 10911992  396928611344              
                 10911993  396943311341              
                 10911994  397088711443              
                 10911995  397208211507
```

Will be exported into separated file `input_B.txt` = `schema` and `input_A.txt` = `lst`

==> output/input_A.lst <==

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 
A   6109.00   6525.00
A   6109.00   6526.00
A   6109.00   6527.00
A   6109.00   6528.00
A   6109.00   6529.00
```

==> output/input_B.schema <==

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 
B   1091.00   1991.00
B   1091.00   1992.00
B   1091.00   1993.00
B   1091.00   1994.00
B   1091.00   1995.00
```

So I [followed the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423495/output-matching-column-from-multiple-input-in-awk).

```
#!/bin/awk -f
FNR==1{
    sub(/.txt/,"",FILENAME)
    lst="output/"FILENAME".lst"
    schema="output/"FILENAME".schema"
    print "Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 " > (lst)
    print "Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 " > (schema)
}
/^                 [6-9]/{
    Name=substr($0,18,4)
    No=substr($0,22,4)
    printf ("A%10.2f%10.2f\n",Name,No) > (lst)
}
/^                 [1-4]/{
    Name=substr($0,18,4)
    No=substr($0,22,4)
    printf ("B%10.2f%10.2f\n",Name,No)> (schema)
}
```

Almost succeeded, I need your advise. I need to skip those unmatched field from being output like this.

```
script.awk *txt

head output/*
==> output/input_A.lst <==
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 
A   6109.00   6525.00
A   6109.00   6526.00
A   6109.00   6527.00
A   6109.00   6528.00
A   6109.00   6529.00

==> output/input_A.schema <== This one should not being output
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 

==> output/input_B.lst <== also this one should not being output, due I'm printing it at the FNR
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 

==> output/input_B.schema <==
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 
B   1091.00   1991.00
B   1091.00   1992.00
B   1091.00   1993.00
B   1091.00   1994.00
B   1091.00   1995.00
```

Comment: Not clear, please do mention which fields you don't want?

Comment: if the `input_A.txt` doesn't found `[1-4]` digit, it's not gonna output any file

Comment: Not clear still, if no match found then ideally it shouldn't print anything to it right? Could you please post more details on same?

Comment: yeah correct, sure, no problem

Comment: Is your Input_file input_A always having digits starting from `[6-9]` and you don't want to get any other digits in it, then we can make it file specific by adding filename into condition. Let me know if this is the cse?

Comment: Not exactly, but for now, the digits is starting as mentioned. And, mostly the data being judge by the filename. `input_A.txt`  will be being concatenated as `A` with other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. This should make sure that at least 1 line is coming into Output file(s) not only header. If a file doesn't have any match then an empty file with only headers will NOT be created by this.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
FNR==1{
    sub(/.txt/,"",FILENAME)
    lst="output/"FILENAME".lst"
    schema="output/"FILENAME".schema"
    count=count1=""        
}
/^                 [6-9]/{
    if(++count==1){
       print "Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 " > (lst)
    }
    Name=substr($0,18,4)
    No=substr($0,22,4)
    printf ("A%10.2f%10.2f\n",Name,No) > (lst)
}
/^                 [1-4]/{
    if(++count1==1){
       print "Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 " > (schema)
    }
    Name=substr($0,18,4)
    No=substr($0,22,4)
    printf ("B%10.2f%10.2f\n",Name,No)> (schema)
}
```

Comment: what the `++count` does?

Comment: @user10254032, Your Welcome. I also added `count=count1=""` in `FNR==1` condition, so that every time it RESETS itself. It makes sure that when a file is having a match then only it should write headers. Also this `++count==1` will make sure that it only writes it 1 time. I hope it is clear now.